# Pass command line args to COM component in WPF project

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, xaml, mfc

So here is the setup:

- C# WPF main project using xaml for layouts
- We have an ancient MFC activeX / COM component that takes uses

  ```
  CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
  ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
  ```

  to get the command line params and operate based on them. *This old project cannot be changed* :(
- Windows Form Class Library project to wrap the COM component.

The component gets added to the xaml view like this:

```
var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
var activeX = new Viewer();
host.Child = activeX;
var grid = new Grid();            
grid.Children.Add(host);
Content = grid
```

How do I pass "command line parameters" that the COM component will pick up when it does its `ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);` ?

update:

my winform uses: private AxPLUGINXLib.AxPluginX axPluginX1;

with class defined below. Still not sure how to pass command line args to it.

```
    [Clsid("{9ab948c6-b1a9-11d2-ac9b-0040c72d55ed}")]
    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public class AxPluginX : AxHost
    {
        public AxPluginX();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        [DispId(-525)]
        public virtual int ReadyState { get; }

        public event _DPluginXEvents_ReadyStateChangeEventHandler ReadyStateChange;

        public virtual void AboutBox();
        protected override void AttachInterfaces();
        protected override void CreateSink();
        protected override void DetachSink();
    }
```

Comment: You're asking what the interface to your COM component is. That's IMHO silly. You are the one sitting on that information.

Comment: that is beyond unhelpful. I know the string I want to pass to the COM component. I don't know HOW to pass it. Like I said it would read it from command line args in a standalone situation.

I need to populate the CCommandLineInfo.m_strFileName field inside the COM component for it to work.

Comment: Is this a COM .exe or COM .dll?  If it's an .exe perhaps you can shell out and start the COM object via its own process (where you can specify whatever command line you want) and then grab the instance using GetObject (instead of CreateObject).

Comment: @TylerZale: Since you "know the string", why is that information not in your question? With more information, no matter what, readers could probably make a less uninformed *guess* about what your problem is. Voted down for the sparsity of information and the double-plus un-nice response to my helpful comment.

Comment: @John Wu: There is a stand alone .exe for this. It was loaded as a reference via its .ocx. We are trying to contain this component within our UI so we can do screencapture/sharing of it and the like, so we could only spawn it as a child executable if there is a good way to capture its window output?

Comment: if 'Viewer' is your winForm control, could you change it and add a new method that will rout your string to activX component?

Comment: @Shakra see updated question.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an old activeX control that your organization uses elsewhere, perhaps with an unmanaged C++ program instead of c#?  And you are now trying to upgrade it?  How does the old application set the command line, exactly?

Comment: @John Wu yes, its an old C++/MFC app. It was used standalone and integrated with IE as an activeX plugin. We are trying to wrap it in a WPF app now. Its uses CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo; ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo); to pull the command line args. Examples: "app.exe http://url.to.pass.in"

Comment: I understand how the command line was retrieved in the past.  But, how was it set in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're doing something that crazy... You could:

Add a new C++/CLI project to your solution: Visual C++ -> CLR -> Class Library.

Then add a function to the C++/CLI class like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

std::vector<wchar_t> ArgBuffer(4096);
std::vector<wchar_t*> ArgTable;

namespace ManagedCpp {

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        static void PassCommandLine(array<String^>^ args)
        {
            size_t totalChars = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < args->Length; i++)
            {
                totalChars += args[i]->Length + 1; // include null-terminator
            }

            ArgBuffer.resize(totalChars);
            ArgTable.resize(args->Length);

            auto pDst = &ArgBuffer[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < args->Length; i++)
            {
                pin_ptr<const wchar_t> pStr = PtrToStringChars(args[i]);
                size_t len = args[i]->Length + 1; // include null-terminator

                std::copy_n(
                    static_cast<const wchar_t*>(pStr),
                    len,
                    stdext::make_checked_array_iterator(pDst, ArgBuffer.size())
                    );
                ArgTable[i] = pDst;
                pDst += len;
            }

            __wargv = &ArgTable[0];
            __argc = ArgTable.size();
        }
    };
}
```

Then, before you call any methods on your ActiveX object, call your new function from your C# application with something like this:

```
ManagedCpp.Class1.PassCommandLine(new[] { "myArg1", "myArg2" });
```

This works by replacing the C-runtime global exports for the command-line arguments. The same globals that ParseCommandLine() references. You may read more about them here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674.aspx